# Given a list of numbers how to insert items into another list with the list of numbers as the index?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of numbers:

```
numbers=[1,3]
```

and I have two list of lists:

```
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] and b=[[1,2],[2,4]]
```

I want to insert the items from list `a` into list `b` according to index in the `numbers` list. So `[1,2,3]` will be inserted into list `b` at index `1` and `[4,5,6]` into list `b` at index `3`. How do I do that?

EDIT:I tried using a for loop but it said list index out of range?
EDIT:The loop is correct.Errors were from other parts of my code.
    for itemOne in numbers:
        for item in a:
           verticeToAppend= item
            b.insert(itemOne,verticeToAppend)

Output:

```
[[1,2],[1,2,3],[2,4],[4,5,6]]
```

Comment: this question should be close, stackoverflow is a website to ask specific problems not to solve your work

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: `for i in range(len(numbers)): b.insert(numbers[i],a[i])`

Comment: just use generator and insert :

`a=(i for i in a)


for i in numbers:
    b.insert(i,a.__next__())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[b.insert(numbers[elem],a[elem]) for elem in range(len(numbers))]
```

You could use a list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

The error I got was from errors in other parts of my code.This for loop is correct.

```
for itemOne in numbers:
for item in a:
   verticeToAppend= item   
    b.insert(itemOne,verticeToAppend)
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert values into a result list according to the indices list (see code).

```
result = []
originals = [...]
values = [...]
while len(indices) > 0:
    if len(result) == indices[0]:
        result.append(values[indices[0]])
        indices = indices[1:]
    elif len(originals) == 0:
        result.append("placeholder") # e. g. None
    else:
        result.append(originals[0])
        originals = originals[1:]
```